# PlayN Maven Archetype and Running HTML5 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, html, google-app-engine, gwt, playn

I generated a skeleton PlayN project from the playn-archetype and imported into Eclipse via m2e after verifying a successful build via

```
mvn clean package
```

After using the Google Plugin for Eclipse to successfully compile the html subproject, I then right click on the html subproject and perform a **Run As -> Web Application...**.  Per the 'Getting Started' instructions on the PlayN wiki, I attempt to load the resulting Development Mode URL minus the *?gwt.codesvr=120.0.0.1:9997* suffix and am greeted with a dialog containing the following:

```
GWT module named 'project' may need to be (re)compiled.
```

I have verified that the *<script>* tag in my *project.html* is pointing to the appropriate javascript file (*project/project.nocache.js*), and I've verified that said javascript file exists and its contents browsed when navigating directly to it (i.e. *http://127.0.0.1:8888/project/project.nocache.js*).

The project works fine (albeit slowly) when the *?gwt.codesvr=120.0.0.1:9997* suffix is part of the URL (which is expected), and it also works fine when running **mvn gae:run** from the html subproject folder and browsing to *http://127.0.0.1:8080/*.

This is more of an annoyance than anything else, but I would at least like to know why it's happening and how to fix it :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you started the web application with "Run as... Web application" you need to recompile the project again (while the web application is running).

When you refresh your browser (be aware of the browser-cache) it should work.

This is a known issue is some older versions of PlayN.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this yet -- I'll update as soon as I do ;)